Loading scripts dynamically fails but loading directly works
I am trying to load js scripts in order without blocking page load. I wrote a function that returns a promise when it resolves and called the function with the script URLs. The scripts load sequentially. Why am I getting these errors:
VM4599 monacoManipulate.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: monaco is not defined at loader.js:657 GET https://example.com/vs/language/typescript/tsMode.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Refused to execute script from 'https://example.com/vs/language/typescript/tsMode.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

When I load the same scripts in the same order directly on head the code works fine. Where did i go wrong when dynamically loading the scripts?
This works:
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" data-name="vs/editor/editor.main" href="/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.css" />

  <script defer>
    var require = {
      paths: {
        vs: '/monaco-editor/min/vs'
      }
    };
  </script>

  <script src="/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js"></script>
  <script src="/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js"></script>
  <script src="/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js"></script>
</head>

But this doesn't:
function loadResource(url, callback) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      var element;
      if (url.endsWith('.js')) {
        element = document.createElement("script");
        element.type = "text/javascript";
        element.src = url;
      } else if (url.endsWith('.css')) {
        element = document.createElement("link");
        element.rel = "stylesheet";
        element.href = url;
        element.type = "text/css";
        if (url === '/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.css') {
          element.dataset.name = "vs/editor/editor.main";
        }
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Unsupported file type ' + url));
        return;
      }

      element.onload = () => {
        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
          resolve(callback());
        } else {
          resolve();
        }
      };
      element.onerror = reject;

      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(element);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("The resource failed to load:", error);
    });
}

const monaco_css = "/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.css";
const monaco_script = "/monaco-editor/min/vs/loader.js";
const monaco_i18n_script = "/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.nls.js";
const monaco_main_script = "/monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js";
const monaco_manipulate = "/js/users/monacoManipulate.js"

loadResource(monaco_css)
  .then(() => loadResource(monaco_script))
  .then(() => loadResource(monaco_i18n_script))
  .then(() => loadResource(monaco_main_script))
  .then(() => loadResource(monaco_manipulate))
  .then(() => {
    require.config({
      paths: {
        'vs': '/monaco-editor/min/vs'
      }
    });
    require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function() {
      console.log("Monaco loaded")
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Some resources failed to load:", error);
  });


Remember that a runnable snippet is supposed to be able to run the code you're showing. That said: why would you (need to) use this code? All it's doing is making it take much longer for the JS and CSS files to load by forcing them to download one by one. At the very least use a Promise.all so they all download at the same time, but even then: why do you think you need this? Loading the script elements up front (but with the async attribute so they don't hold up the page) means the browser can cache them.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't want to load the scripts on page load. I want to load the script when a certain condition is met. Loading the scripts on page load will increase the page load time for no reason and the user might not even use the certain feature.

No it won't: add the async attribute to your script tags. Done, nothing gets held up. (this is something you typically always want to do, with any "this needs to run only once the page is ready for modification" scripts also using the defer attribute)

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I didn't know about that. Does it mean when using async in script tags the script loads when a code snippet depending on the script is executed?

No, it loads as part of the initial page load, but without blocking the rest of the page load. Note that this makes all of them completely independent, so there's no load order you can rely on. However, you can also add the defer attribute (so you have <script src="..." async defer></script>) to make sure that the scripts all get downloaded independently, but won't get run until the page is ready for modifications, and get run in the order you wrote. So you're still "loading monaco up front", but it doesn't hold anything up, and it's immediately available once you need it.

ah Thanks! Mind adding it as an answer so that I can accept it?

given the actual intent, I'll close it as a duplicate of one of the questions about how to load scripts in order, the modern way already asked before =)
